# Check form input from different pages

Tags: php

It can be possible to check different form input into a single page?
For example, if i have a page (input.php) and (signup.php), can I check input into a single page called (check.php) instead to create 2 pages for both input?
And this solution, is better or not?

Comment: Yes, just put the one below the other in a single form.

Comment: _"is better or not"_ - That's 100% dependent on the rest of your structure and preference. Only you can make that decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use the same PHP script (e.g. `check.php`) to check form input from two different pages. You just need to make sure that your check script is able to distinguish where the input is coming from. If its not obvious based on the provided parameters, I would suggest putting a hidden field on both forms that indicates which it is.

If one is better than the other depends on the situation and can not be generally answered.

You can even have both forms and the check in the same PHP script. Messy, but technically doable.